# Kafka offsets and consumer group issue

Tags: apache-kafka, distributed-computing, publish-subscribe, distributed-transactions

My Kafka partition got 20 offsets. I have a consumer group of 5 consumer subscribed. **My Question** is, is it possible to ensure that first 5 offsets will be read by consumer 1, after successful read next 5 offsets will be read by consumer 2 and so on..? If not possible then is there any open source tool/technology available to do so?

Comment: I think by offset you mean messages. You can have multiple partition for the topic and each consumer in the group is reading from separate partition. You can have your own custom logic to block other consumers from reading until the first one has finished

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two consumers belonging to the same consumer group can't read from the same partition. If there is only one partition, one consumer will consume all 20 offsets, and remaining consumers will be idle until a new partition is added.